# Class implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

I've got a problem with a class I'm trying to construct within another. I am new to C++ (coming from Java) and I don't understand why my header file isn't good...

To make things short, I am creating an app that allows to create, edit and save+load a map made of walls. I wrote a class Wall that receives parameters plus the QGraphicsScene on MainWindow in order to link the Wall class to its graphical representation.
I'm using Qt for the graphical aspects. As I am new to it, things tend to blow up in my hands.
The MainWindow has a createWall() function that is called whenever a QDialog emits accepted() and its data are gathered and sent to the function.

wall.h

```
#ifndef WALL_H
#define WALL_H

#include <QtWidgets>

class Wall
{
public:
    explicit Wall(float x = 0, float y = 0, float lent = 0, float th = 0, float eps = 0, float sig = 0, QGraphicsScene *scene = nullptr);
    ~Wall();

    float getX() const;
    void setX(float value);

    float getY() const;
    void setY(float value);

    float getLent() const;
    void setLent(float value);

    float getTh() const;
    void setTh(float value);

    float getEps() const;
    void setEps(float value);

    float getSig() const;
    void setSig(float value);

    QGraphicsScene *getScene() const;
    void setScene(QGraphicsScene *value);

private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float lent;
    float th;
    float eps;
    float sig;
    QGraphicsRectItem rect;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
};

#endif // WALL_H
```

wall.cpp

```
#include "wall.h"

Wall::Wall(float x1, float y1, float lent1, float th1, float eps1, float sig1, QGraphicsScene *scene1)
{
    this->x = x1;
    this->y = y1;
    this->lent = lent1;
    this->th = th1;
    this->eps = eps1;
    this->sig = sig1;
    this->scene = scene1;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rect;
    QBrush blackBrush(Qt::black);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(1);
    rect = scene->addRect(0,0,10,50,blackPen,blackBrush);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
}
...
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::createWall(float th, float eps, float sig)
{
    std::cout << "Thickness = " << th << "\nPermittivity = " << eps << "\nConductivity = " << sig << "\n";
    Wall wall(0,0,50,th,eps,sig,scene);
    walls.push_back(wall);
    wall_number++;
    std::cout << "Wall number = " << wall_number << "\n";
}
```

3 errors in wall.h:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136: error: use of deleted function ‘Wall::Wall(const Wall&)’

{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/home/.../wall.h:6: error: ‘QGraphicsRectItem::QGraphicsRectItem(const QGraphicsRectItem&)’ is private within this context

/home/.../wall.h:6: error: use of deleted function ‘QGraphicsRectItem::QGraphicsRectItem(const QGraphicsRectItem&)’

class Wall
      ^~~~
```

Maybe I'm doing something extremely stupid here... I've searched and it seems that my constructor simply does not work for it is deleted by default. Yet I think I have initialized it correctly haven't I?

Comment: The problem is within compiler-generated copy constructor which is ill-formed because `QGraphicsRectItem` is not copyable.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get better answers check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. My tip for future debugging of similar issues: have your code in a version-control system and roll back until your code works again. Then diff the changes for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got yourself confused because your class has a private member `QGraphicsRectItem rect;` while your constructor has a local variable `QGraphicsRectItem *rect;`.

Change your class' `rect` into a pointer, remove the `QGraphicsRectItem *rect;` declaration line in the constructor body and you're good.

To prevent memory 'leaks' you should delete the `QGraphicsRectItem` in the destructor. (It doesn't leak memory, because all items are owned by the scene, but the items would start conglomerating in your scene.)

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed it was a confusion... Also I had forgotten to add a definition to the destructor, hence the deletion problems.